# jQueryRotate plugin set delay

Tags: jquery

jQuery :

```
$("#image").rotate({
    angle: 0,
    center: ["50%", "100%"],
    duration: 5000,
    animateTo: 15
});
```

I want to set delay to this.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "I want to set delay to this"? Are you saying you want this to happen after a certain amount of time?

Comment: I put this code for #image2 , #image3 so I want to animate after one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like what you need is to use a callback, which is called by `rotate()` when the animation finishes.  According to [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Documentation#callback) you can pass a `callback` parameter like this:

```
$("#image").rotate({
    angle: 0,
    center: ["50%", "100%"],
    duration: 5000,
    animateTo: 15,
    callback: function() {
        $("#image2").rotate({
            angle: 0,
            center: ["50%", "100%"],
            duration: 5000,
            animateTo: 15
        });
    }
});
```

You can pass another callback into #image2 for #image3 etc.